# ROS2 data received at Zenoh, Not able to deserialize

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, deserialization, ros2, zenon-network

I am receiving the data in sample.payload but i am not able to deserialize the data.

Data format:

```
b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00Demo20\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00gap\x00\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00@{\x14\x8e?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd3\x02\x96I\x07\x00\x00\x00tripid\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00Demo20\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00position\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa5\xbdJAH\x90\x9eB\x00\x00\x00@\xd3\x02\x96I\x07\x00\x00\x00tripid\x00\x00'
```

Getting a struct error.

> struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 1065353260 bytes for unpacking 1 bytes at offset 1065353259 (actual buffer size is 92)

where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using `pycdr`, as done in [this example](https://github.com/eclipse-zenoh/zenoh-demos/blob/41c931c0e5eec948307936cbf7fe1008dc3efac7/ROS2/zenoh-python-teleop/ros2-teleop.py#L21), you should check if the Python class you defined for the expected deserialized type correspond exactly to the ROS2 message definition.

In this same example, the [Log class](https://github.com/eclipse-zenoh/zenoh-demos/blob/41c931c0e5eec948307936cbf7fe1008dc3efac7/ROS2/zenoh-python-teleop/ros2-teleop.py#L44) corresponds exactly to the [ROS2 Log message](https://github.com/ros2/rcl_interfaces/blob/3aecf019ea2612bd7142c52813e4809b724e5785/rcl_interfaces/msg/Log.msg#L32) (ordering of fields is important).